# How to tell Zeitwerk to ignore overrides folder in a rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

In the latest Rails 7.1.2 my engines have stopped working with the following error

```
Zeitwerk::NameError:
  expected file /home/jamie/Development/rails/comtech/r7/ccs_cms/engines/admin_dashboard/app/overrides/add_admin_dashboard_link_to_core_header.rb to define constant AddAdminDashboardLinkToCoreHeader, but didn't
```

It is my understanding that this is due to zeitwerk autoloading files in the engines app/overrides folder.
Prior to the latest Rails release I have had the following code in an initializer in my engine.rb

```
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
...
      initializer "let the main autoloader ignore this engine's overrides" do
        overrides = Engine.root.join("app/overrides")
        Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(overrides)
      end

  config.to_prepare do
    overrides = Engine.root.join("app", "overrides")
    Dir.glob("#{overrides}/**/*.rb").sort.each do |override|
      load override
    end
    decorators = Engine.root.join("app", "decorators")
    Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(decorators)
    Dir.glob(Engine.root.join("app", "decorators", "**", "*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
      Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
    end
  end
```

This has been happily working up until now and it follows the Documentation which shows the following example on ignoring and loading folders and files specifically overrides

```
# config/application.rb module MyApp   class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    overrides = "#{Rails.root}/app/overrides"
    Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(overrides)

    config.to_prepare do
      Dir.glob("#{overrides}/**/*_override.rb").sort.each do |override|
        load override
      end
    end   end end
```

What is the solution to this now please? Or have I hit a Rails bug? Or have I just got it wrong somehow?, up to and including Rails 7.1 this was not an issue

*Update*
It seems I have more than this to deal with. Upgrading to Rails 7.1.2 from Rails 7.1.1 seems to have caused a lot more issues than originally realised.
Latest log from starting the rails server shows

```
/home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails.rb:51:in `configuration': undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

      application.config
                 ^^^^^^^
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/factory_bot_rails-6.4.0/lib/factory_bot_rails/railtie.rb:25:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:97:in `class_eval'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:97:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:87:in `with_execution_control'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:92:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:78:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:77:in `each'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:77:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:338:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.1.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.1.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.1.0/lib/database_cleaner-active_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/Development/rails/comtech/r7/ccs_cms/engines/admin_dashboard/test/dummy/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:139:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:136:in `perform'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:178:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:73:in `perform'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:71:in `block in invoke'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/engine/commands.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@cms_admin_dashboard/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from bin/rails:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: At first sight, I don't see why the autoloder should be looking into the engine's app/overrides at all, since it is ignored. Could you please throw Rails.autoloaders.log! into config/application.rb, reproduce the error, and share the traces? (BTW, Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(decorators) should be also in the initializer, it has to run once and before setup.)

Comment: Another question, why does the engine have overrides? Overrides normally are located in the parent application only.

Comment: @XavierNoria, The engine is overriding a view in another engine. regarding the app/overrides being ignored, up until this latest Rails 7.1.2, the overrides were indeed being ignored but now they are not. My question is why not? and how to ignore them now in the latest 7.1.2 Rails version? I'll add the autoloaders log and move the decorators ignore functionality to an initializer, it was an oversight.

Comment: @XavierNoria Your comments lead me to believe I've hot a bug in the latest release! I will post the log output shortly

Comment: Awesome, if more bandwidth is necessary please create an issue in rails/rails and tag me (@fxn). We can always followup here to close the question if necessary.

Comment: @Xavier, Really appreciate the help. It looks like 7.1.2 has broken a lot more than this, see my update, up until now I have been running my test suite within Guard but now I come to run the server I get the error I just posted. I'll' investigate further and come back to this later.

Comment: @XavierNoria see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/50126

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256010/discussion-between-jamesc-and-xavier-noria).